# Can I unpopulate a Git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Once I run

```
git update submodule
```

can I do anything to make it go back to the way it was before init and update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that you want to go back to before **init** and **update**, which would be the situation where the submodule is still present in `.gitmodules`, but is an empty directory which isn't registered in `.git/config`.

Suppose your submodule is called `foo/bar`, then you could do the following:

```
# Move the submodule out of your repository, just in case you have changes
# in there that you realise afterwards that you'd like to preserve:
mv foo/bar/ ~/backups/old-foo-bar/

# Recreate the submodule directory, but empty this time:
mkdir foo/bar/

# Remove all the config variables associated with that submodule:
git config --remove-section submodule.foo/bar
# Note that the submodule name is *without* the trailing slash
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (with git1.8.3, April 22d 2013) a:

```
git submodule deinit
```

(See "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)")

> This removes the whole `submodule.<name>` section from `.git/config` either for the given submodule(s)

You might have to delete the working tree for that submodule though.

Answer (score 0):

**If you changes were commited**, then you should be able to check the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

Once you find the change set you lost you can merge it back in.

**If your changes were not commited**, then they cannot be recovered.

Comment: What I wanted was a way to preserve the submodule, but just remove the populated files in my workspace.  Turns out, I can just delete the directory and it doesn't affect the submodule in any way.  So, in my case, my submodules are in a directory named projects.  I can just remove projects/toolchain and the contents are gone, but git doesn't record the deletion.  Thanks to everyone for trying this one.